# C++ Function that takes an array, a predicate and a operator as arguments and apply the operator to array's element where predicate is satisfied

Tags: c++, function, c++11, templates, predicate

I'm trying to write a function as described in title. 
I made a template custom dynamic array called queue, and i need to create a function that checks for every element of this queue if a predicate passed by argument is satisfied; if it is, i need to apply an operator to that element also passed by argument.

First of all I probably need an explanation.. the predicate should be unary so it could be something like "isdigit" or "isalpha", right? and as operator it could be something like a simple post-increment ++. 
The main problem is that I really don't have any idea how can I pass operators and predicates as parameters in function.

If I understood the request, here what I tried to do but of course is not working... anyone helping out?

```
template<typename L, typename OPERATOR>

void change_if(queue<L> &que, bool (*f)(L), OPERATOR op) {

    for(int i=0; i<que._size-1; i++) {
        if ((*f)(que._queue[i]))
            que._queue[i] = op(que._queue[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    //as constructor, 3 is referred to size of the queue and 99 to the values.
    queue<int> q(3, 99);

    change_if(q, isdigit, ++);

}
```

Comment: What is not working? Does the program compile? Does it give the wrong output? Also, if you're not sure how to pass predicates and operators to a function, try doing it with a plain array, or `vector` before attempting it on your custom array.

Comment: as an example operator you give the post-increment ++, but a post increment operator would not have the intended effect here `que._queue[i] = op(que._queue[i]);`

Comment: You can't pass operators anywhere, you need to wrap them in a callable of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest to pass the predicate also with a inferred type, so you can also pass lambdas, i.e.

```
template<typename L, typename P, typename OP>
void change_if(queue<L> &que, P pred, OP op) {
  for(...)
    if(pred(que._queue[i]))
       que._queue[i] = op(que._queue[i]);
}
```

Your idea is a bit inconsistent, as you do the assignment (`que._queue[i] = op(que._queue[i]);`) and then come up with the idea that `op` should be something like the post-increment operator.
Both together would boil down to `a = a++` which has no effect.

You could go one of two ways:

1. think of "op" as a function, getting an element and returning an altered one, i.e. `L op(const L&l) { return l+1; }`. Then use the code above and call
   `change_if(q, [](auto && l) { return std::isdigit(l); }, [](auto && l) { return l + 1});`
2. think of "op" as a function, changing the element it got, i.e. `void op(L&l) { l++;}`. Then use `if(pred(...)) op(que._queue[i])` and call
   `change_if(q, [](auto && l) { return std::isdigit(l); }, [](auto && l) { l++; });`

As a side note: you cannot simply take the address of `std::isdigit` as it is overloaded so I wrapped the call in a lambda here.

Another side note: I don't know your queue implementation but `< size-1` in the for loop's condition looks a bit like you're missing the last element.